# One batch file - multiple commands - no waiting

Tags: batch-file, multiple-instances

I really have looked at multiple examples here, but I cannot get this to work - all the examples have a situation where you just call a command that actually does end, I need to keep mine running. This is what I need to do.

To configure a network device, I have the option to do so with an `arp` command, and a ping command, but these need to be executed in the same command prompt, but each device needs to be in it's own window.

I need to run `arp -s 192.168.5.5 00-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC` and when that is finished, I need to run `ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.5`.
These two commands have to run in the same command window.  I would like to open lets say 30 of these at the same time, arp'ing and pinging the same address in that specific window, but different addresses in each other window (I hope this makes sense).

right now, I can get it to run, but it waits for the first command to finish, before starting the second.  I have used the `START`, but that does not work either.

Yes, I guess I could create 30 different batch files, but that would defeat the object, as I need to configure over 500 devices, so creating 500 batch files would take just as long; unless a batch file can create all the required batch files for me?

So, I have an excel spreadsheet that creates all the lines I need in the batch file, and I was hoping to use this:

```
start cmd.exe /K arp -s 192.168.5.5 00-40-8C-D4-FB-BC && ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.5   
start cmd.exe /K arp -s 192.168.5.6 00-40-8C-D4-F9-A9 && ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.6    
start cmd.exe /K arp -s 192.168.5.7 00-40-8C-D4-FB-F6 && ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.7    
start cmd.exe /K arp -s 192.168.5.8 00-40-8C-D4-FC-70 && ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.8  
start cmd.exe /K arp -s 192.168.5.9 00-40-8C-D4-FB-F4 && ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.9
start cmd.exe /K arp -s 192.168.5.10 00-40-8C-D4-FB-F8 && ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.10
```

So using the above, only the first command actually runs.  If I set it to ping only say 300 times, it would switch to the next, but again this would defeat the object because I need to do 30 devices at once, so waiting for each to finish first would take forever.

Perhaps I am totally on the wrong track here, perhaps someone has a far better idea?  Bare in mind, that each of the above commands has to run in its own command prompt window, otherwise the arp command fails if you try to do too many at the same time.

For clarity also, I need to run the arp command, and when that is complete run the ping command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your &&s, and maybe change to just &:

```
start cmd.exe /K arp -s 192.168.5.5 00-40-8C-D4-FB-BC ^& ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.5
```

But, escaping in cmd can get tricky very quickly. I recommend you create a single DoPing.cmd with everything you need:

```
arp -s %1 %2
ping -l 408 -t %1
```

And call it from your generated cmd:

```
start cmd.exe /K DoPing.cmd 192.168.5.5 00-40-8C-D4-FB-BC
```

Of course, this means you need to deploy DoPing.cmd to wherever you're running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... The first option worked better, but it is running all the arp commands in the first command prmpt, and then opening a new command prompt just for the ping command, which I am not understanding why.  If I want to use your second option of using %1 and %2?  I guess those are variables that I need to define somewhere? where would I define that list of MAC addresses and IP addresses?

Comment: I tested with a single `^&` and it worked. I assumed you used `&&` on purpose - I guess escaping doesn't work the way I expect.
You don't define vars in batch files - the first parameter is %1, the second is %2, etc - as you can see in my sample.

Comment: I guess I did not really grasp what you were trying to brig across, sorry for that, but after thinking it through properly I tested this and it also works great - I now have two working options.  Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your data is in a text file this way:

```
192.168.5.5 00-40-8C-D4-FB-BC
192.168.5.6 00-40-8C-D4-F9-A9
192.168.5.7 00-40-8C-D4-FB-F6
192.168.5.8 00-40-8C-D4-FC-70
192.168.5.9 00-40-8C-D4-FB-F4
192.168.5.10 00-40-8C-D4-FB-F8
```

The Batch file below create multiple Batch files, each one with the required commands, and start they. Each created Batch file deletes itself after finished its business.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (theDataFile.txt) do (
   echo @echo off > %%b.bat
   echo arp -s %%a %%b >> %%b.bat
   echo ping -l 408 -t %%a >> %%b.bat
   echo del %%b.bat ^& exit >> %%b.bat
   start %%b.bat
)
```

Comment: I tested this now, this option does work.  Do you think there there will be an issue of running this for 30 or 40 windows at a time?  And although it is not really a problem, it is not deleting the batch files when finished - remember it is a continuous ping it is running, so the only way to stop it is to Ctrl+C which then kills the whole batch file - I mean heck, I can just go delete all the batch files when it is done, I just wanted to point that out.  I am also fiddling with the other two options below, but I am glad I have this one that works so far - thanks!!

Comment: I used this to test yesterday, and it worked great - I will still fiddle around with the other options around here and see how I can get this to be most elegant.  I REALLY appreciate your help here!

Answer (score 0):

Try quotes around your whole argument and also maybe use & rather than &&

eg

```
start cmd.exe /K "arp -s 192.168.5.5 00-40-8C-D4-FB-BC & ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.5"
```

Comment: This option also worked, but as with the other option it runs all of the arp commands in the first command window, and then creates a new window for each ping command.  But at least this is further than what I was.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @sigmoore your command is running but the quoted argument is bad.  **Cmd.exe "/K more args"**

Answer (score 0):

On problem is that you need to quote the arguments being passed to CMD.  Your original is :

```
start cmd.exe /K arp -s 192.168.5.5 00-40-8C-D4-FB-BC && ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.5
```

This syntax will launch a CMD window and pass the ARP command to that window as an argument, but not the && ping portion.  Instead, that is treated as the command to run after the START.

To correct this we can add quotes that will explicitly pass the arp and ping as a single argument to the CMD.

```
start cmd.exe /K "arp -s 192.168.5.5 00-40-8C-D4-FB-BC && ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.5"
```

Additionally, [I see it suggested](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) that the start command should always be provided a title, even if the title is null. So....

```
start "" cmd.exe /K "arp -s 192.168.5.5 00-40-8C-D4-FB-BC && ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.5"
```

Of course you have further options.  The && runs the second command only if the first returns successful.  So in theory & could be used to ensure that the second command always runs.  Then again there's no reason to both pinging if the arp call fails so && works to...

I assume you are leaving the new CMD windows open on purpose so you can see the results, but you could always use a /c instead of /k to auto close them.

As a note with the /c. You mention in a response to another answer that hitting control+c kills all windows.  This is normal behavior, but running CMD with a /c should make the control+c only apply to the current window.   Changing the following line in the other answer:

```
start %%b.bat
```

to...

```
start cmd /c %%b.bat
```

(or something similar) should let you use CTRL+C in individual windows spawned by the loop.

Comment: Thanks - the problem is still that if I list a bunch of the command under each other in the same batch file, it will still only open the next CMD window after the first ping cycle has completed.  So to test I used -n 10 so that the pings would end, and then it does open the second window, and so forth.  I need it to open all 20 or 50 windows at the same time.  Your other pointers were a great help, thank you... it seems like I missed some important aspects of the switches I have been using - I am still learning here (as we all really are), so these pointers help a lot!  Thank you!

Comment: Really? If I make a test file, something like:

`start "" cmd /k "echo command 1 && ping -t localhost"
start "" cmd /k "echo command 1 && ping -t localhost"
start "" cmd /k "echo command 1 && ping -t localhost"
start "" cmd /k "echo command 1 && ping -t localhost"
start "" cmd /k "echo command 1 && ping -t localhost"`

I will end up with six windows.  Five of them will be running continous pings, the sixth will be the original window that ran the batch, and each of them can be stopped individually with a CTRL+C.

Comment: Wow, just realized how terribly the formatting for that came out in the comment. It is just `start "" cmd /k "echo command 1 && ping -t localhost" ` five times.

Comment: Assuming you are already using Aacini's for loop above and have all the data in a text file as described, you could also try something like this: `for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (theDataFile.txt) do ( start "" cmd /k "arp -s %%a %%b && ping -l 408 -t %%a" )` Gets rid of the need to build a bunch of intermediate batch files.

Comment: @0x90h: Can I split the comand `start cmd.exe /K "arp -s 192.168.5.5 00-40-8C-D4-FB-BC && ping -l 408 -t 192.168.5.5"` into multiple lines?

Comment: @PauloCardoso : You mean remove the &&?  You could, but the object of the && is to make passing two commands to the new instance of cmd.exe easy.  If you removed that you could make a new .bat that had the two commands in it and then pass the name of the .bat as the argument to cmd.exe, but then you have to deal with generating the new .bat's and deleting them on completion, etc.

Comment: Basically once you spawn the new cmd.exe and it starts doing its thing it is hard (impossible?) to send it new commands.  So passing the commands as an argument or putting them in a new script and passing that as an argument becomes the easiest method.